# Установка .CAB файлов на Windows

Tags: windows, файлы

Доброго времени суток!
Уверен, что для всех присутствующих здесь (кроме меня) вопрос пятикопеечный.
Загрузил купленный в интернет-магазине дистрибутив такого вида

http://clip2net.com/s/6j3Fre

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно установить это на компьютер (ОС: Windows 7).
Я так понимаю, что простым их разархивированием дело не обойдется.
Может быть программы есть какие специальные? (Вроде CabInstaller для WinMobile )
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А это не многотомный архив?

Comment: а за что минусуют-то? Вопрос вроде бы не такой очевидный, да и ТС не производит впечатление школоты. Наверное, вопрос несколько не по теме, поскольку к программированию отношения не имеет, но об этом можно просто сказать

Comment: Наверное из-за того, что занимаюсь ерундой)
...Но просто на самом деле стало очень интересно.

Answer (score 1):

```
pkgmgr /ip /m:<path><file name>.cab
```

есть еще DISM, который идет как замена pkgmgr и т.п.

http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/4939-how-to-use-windows-7-dism-by-muiz/
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825265.aspx